# how to jquery $("#elementid span")[1].html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

When I try to do

```
$("#elementid span")[1].html();
```

says 'html is not a function'. I always  do it like that

```
$($("#elementid span")[1]).html();
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: [`$('#elementid span').eq(1).html()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: `$("#elementid span:eq(1)").html();`

Comment: The indexed properties in the jQuery object are DOM element references, not jQuery objects.

Comment: @shrys He wants the second one tho :)

Comment: my bad, thank you for pointing that out guys

Comment: @Phil tnx. that was what i looking for.